# Using RemoteMessage instance on a different class

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, firebase-cloud-messaging

Firebase onMessageReceived method provides the remoteMessage instance to get the message or the notification sent. How can I send the remoteMessage instance from a class that extends FirebaseMessagingService to a recyclerviewAdapter to update the list of items in the recyclerview?

Answer (score 0):

I would just copy the data from the remote message to a bean, then send the bean to the adapter.

Comment: please illustrate